# Lost included entity after detaching the objectcontext

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf, entity-framework-4

considering the following code which resides in a service (WCF):

```
 using (var context = new ctxEntities())
            {
                var result = context.MyTable.Include("LinkedTable")
                                   .Where(c => c.RepairID == repairID).ToList();
                result.ForEach(e => context.Detach(e));
                return result;
            }
```

I want to access the LinkedTable properties in a WPF environment, and want (or have?) to detach the context.
Before detaching the context (result.foreach....) i can "see" the LinkedTable as a property of Table.
After detaching the context the LinkedTable property of the Table is null.

How can i prevent this behavior?

Paul

Answer (score 0):

`Detach` also unloads the related ends of the entry in the relationship manager.

It helps if you eliminate the need to detach by turning off tracking upfront. This is an improvement anyway because it removes the overhead of attaching/detaching.

```
using (var context = new ctxEntities())
{
    context.MyTable.MergeOption = MergeOption.NoTracking;
    var result = context.MyTable.Include("LinkedTable")
                       .Where(c => c.RepairID == repairID).ToList();
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Gert,

I Implemented the NoTracking Option results in the serviceClient.Completed event (im using the async WCF Method of getting the data)

this.sc.Completed += (s,e) 0> { this.rep = e.Result };
an error that the connection is closed...

Comment: I don't see how this could be caused by setting `NoTracking`. Nothing async happens between the setting and the execution of the query.

Answer (score 0):

Does this help

```
using(var context = new ctxEntities()){
    context.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
    context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
    //....
```

Comment: It's about `ObjectContext`, not `DbContext` ﾂ